# Is there any way to increase space between fraction bar in powerpoint equation?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, equations

I have typed a fraction in equation editor of Powerpoint slide as follows which does not look well . I am not finding any option for increasing spaces between fraction bar:
[image]

Here is the link of the file which produces the issue:

[Link of problematic file where equation is condensed and overlapped](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1h63LCcz27ft6LzdX1yX0NlK-igs6BlDo/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112966113016285973244&rtpof=true&sd=true)

But you can see the fractions are condensed and even overlapped on the fraction bar. So I actually need the fraction along with fraction bar will look like below:
[image]

How to achieve that (Increasing space between fraction bar and equation) ?

Comment: How much vertical space have you allowed for the equation; what happens if you create a temporary page and move/copy the equation there?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. The Equation editor is working correctly, not issue when when typing your equation, everything is normal. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tx6W.png

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio, Problem is image can't be seen from i.stack.imgur.com. So I can't see your image and I assume you were not able to see my images as well which are in the question!

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid I saw your images (don't know why you can't see [mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tx6W.png)). When I type your equation, the spacing is fine on my side.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I have updated my question with the link of the problematic file. Please download that ppt file and check the equation on the 2nd slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your equation is not long (I opened the posted file), you can insert the spacing by following the steps below:

1. Put your cursor next to the subscript.
2. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then press <kbd>Space</kbd>

You can repeat step 2 to increase the spacing and/or make the fractions an different parts of the equation properly aligned.

**Demo using the posted file**

[image: Demo]

Comment: Worked like a charm for the upper part but what's about the lower part below the fraction bar? How can I increase space between fraction bar and lower part of equation? If I press "Enter" before "1", it is creating a hollow dotted square box over the "1". By the by, still I can't see your demo along with my own posted images, don't know why?

Comment: To increase the space between fraction bar and lower part of equation, put the cursor, press Enter before the 1, then click/select the square box and press space. I don't know why you can't see my posted images, maybe a mod can help with that.

Comment: Worked!! Thankyou very much for your cordial help (But I can't still see the images).